# reading and displaying content by using a socket in c

Tags: c, sockets

I have to implement a function that allows to read the contents of the standard input and to send it to a socket while allowing to display the standard output of what is read on this same socket.

The maximum size of the buffer is 1024 bytes.

void read_write(int sfd);

sfd is the socket file descriptor

we're expected to return when we reach an EOF

```
void read_write(int sdf){
    int n = 1;
    char buffer[1024];
    while(n>0){
        n = read(sdf,buffer,1024);
        if(n==0) break;
        fprintf(stdout,"%s",buffer);
        fflush(stdout);

        memset(buffer,'\0',256);
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far but I don't know how to send it to the socket nor am I sure if I'm doing it correctly (I am unsure as to how to test this locally on a pc)

I also would like to use poll but I don't know either how to apply it in this situation

Comment: sockets do not have a standard input.  You can read from standard input and write that data to the socket, and you can read from the socket and write that data to stdout, but "the standard output of what is read" doesn't really make any sense.  The socket is a file descriptor.  STDIN_FILENO is a file descriptor.  STDOUT_FILENO is a file descriptor.  You can treat all of them basically the same way.

Comment: I phrased it badly. I meant to say that we wanted to read from the standard input of the socket.

Comment: "standard input of the socket" does not mean anything.

Comment: You just want to read from the socket.

Comment: yes precisely.I would like to read from the stdin.

Comment: This is not an easy homework problem. I had to solve this for reasons a month ago; it took hours. But I'm concerned about getting this far and can't even put a mockup of a solution in the question, nor any specific difficulty involved.

Comment: @underscore_d i just added what I have so far but it seems useless

Comment: I have been monitoring; and I think I understand where you are having difficulty. Rather than type a multi-thousand word answer I'm going to refer you to `man 2 select` and `man 2 select_tut`. Or perchance you're expected to use `fork()` but for a networking class `select` is more likely the expected approach.

Comment: @Joshua unfortunately I have to use poll and not select. I read the man page for poll ( ```int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);```) and i don't understand how to find nfds term since it says "the number of items" in my case the buffer has a max capacity of 1024 bytes so should i put 1024 bytes ?

Comment: @a_confused_student: nfds is clearly the number of structs in the array of structs passed to poll.

Comment: It's kinda trivial to implement with two threads.